# src is undefined variable on image swap

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having problems with a (probably) simple task of passing a variable as a src of an image.

The variables are defined at random from an array, and then if URL criteria is met then that random variable is assigned as the src of the image.

**jQuery:**

```
var imgpathnamesfor7offers = ["offers1.jpg", "offers2.jpg", "offers3.jpg", "offers4.jpg"];
var randompathname = imgpathnamesfor7offers[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgpathnamesfor7offers.length)];
var produrl = jQuery(location).attr('href');
var icatRef = produrl.split("/")[4];
if (icatRef == "shark-steam-cleaning") {
    jQuery("#prodpagesliderbar-img").attr("src", jQuery("#prodpagesliderbar-img").attr("src").replace(randompathname));
}
```

Link: http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/uk/shark-steam-cleaning/shark-lift-away-steam-pocket-5-in-1/invt/s06lt30100000001

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Console appends 'undefined' to the end of the src.

Comment: `.replace(randompathname)` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this:

```
jQuery("#prodpagesliderbar-img").attr("src").replace(randompathname)
```

this should be:

```
jQuery("#prodpagesliderbar-img").attr("src", randompathname)
```

Comment: Still undefined @Jai :(

Comment: Just to clarify, this is your corrected if statement:

if (icatRef == "shark-steam-cleaning") {
        jQuery("#prodpagesliderbar-img").attr("src", jQuery("#prodpagesliderbar-img").attr("src", randompathname));
    }

Comment: It was a templaing issue in the end that sorted it. Your code is correct :)